# Error java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0

Tags: java, sql, jsf, primefaces, fileupload

Tengo este programa

Class SubirImagen

```
package Pruebas;

import com.mysql.jdbc.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

import org.primefaces.event.FileUploadEvent;
import org.primefaces.model.UploadedFile;

@ManagedBean
public class SubirImagen {

    private UploadedFile file;

    public UploadedFile getFile() {
        return file;
    }

    public void setFile(UploadedFile file) {
        this.file = file;
    }

    public void upload() {
        try{
        if (file != null) {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/pruebajpa", "root", "admin");

            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO pruebajpa.img (img) VALUES ('?');");
            ps.setBinaryStream(1, file.getInputstream());
            ps.executeUpdate();
            con.close();
            FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage("Succesful", file.getFileName() + " is uploaded.");
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, message);
        }
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Error     " + e); 
        }
    }
}
```

upload.xhtml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">


    <h:head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    </h:head>


    <h:body>
        <h:form>

            <p:galleria value="#{galeria.images}" var="image" panelWidth="500" panelHeight="313" showCaption="true">
                <p:graphicImage name="imagenes/#{image}" alt="Image Description for #{image}" title="#{image}"/>

            </p:galleria>


        </h:form>

        <h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <p:growl id="messages" showDetail="true" />

            <p:fileUpload value="#{subirImagen.file}" mode="simple" skinSimple="true"/>

            <p:commandButton value="Submit2" ajax="false" actionListener="#{subirImagen.upload()}" disabled="false" />
        </h:form>

        <h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">

            <p:growl showDetail="true" />
            <p:fileUpload value="#{uploadBean.file}" mode="simple" />
            <p:commandButton ajax="false" value="Subir" actionListener="#{uploadBean.upload()}" />

        </h:form>


    </h:body> 
</html>
```

Intento subir la imagen pero en la línea ps.setBinaryStream(1, file.getInputstream()); deja de ejecutarse y manda la excepción pueden ayudarme?

Comment: Prueba ingresando 0 en vez de 1.. (No lo he analizado completamente)

Comment: Que estructura tiene la tabla `pruebajpa.img`, es decir sus columnas y tipos de datos

Comment: Unicamente el campo img de tipo blob

Comment: Cuando cambio por 0 el error es este: java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (0 > 1)

Comment: Danni bienvenido a Stackoverflow. Al menos tu consulta está **mal escrita**. Cuando usas consultas preparadas, **no debes nunca encerrar entre comillas el marcador de posición `?`**. Intenta escribir la consulta así: **`INSERT INTO pruebajpa.img (img) VALUES (?);`** Por cierto, ¿tu tabla se llama `pruebajpa.img` o se llama `pruebajpa`?

Comment: se llama img en la tabla pruebajpa, efectivamente era el problema de las comillas, te agradezco mucho ya funciona perfecto. Muchas gracias por tu aporte

Answer (score 0):

Tu consulta está mal escrita:

**<s>`INSERT INTO pruebajpa.img (img) VALUES ('?');`</s>**

Cuando usas consultas preparadas, **no debes nunca encerrar entre comillas el marcador de posición `?`**.

Intenta escribir la consulta así:

**`INSERT INTO pruebajpa.img (img) VALUES (?);`**

También, asegúrate de que tu tabla se llama `pruebajpa.img`... da la impresión de que estás colocando el nombre de la columna al final de la tabla.

Si la tabla se llamase `pruebajpa`, entonces la consulta debería ser escrita así:

**`INSERT INTO pruebajpa (img) VALUES (?);`**